# Has FinancialData forgotten how to deliver monthly data?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, financialdata

I seem to get odd results from the following `FinancialData` code:

```
FinancialData["SP500", "Jan. 1, 1978", "Month"]
```

This gives me a `TimeSeries` of 11,372 "Daily" data points.

[image]

I expected to get ~460 "Month" values, similar to what I get from the following `WolframAlpha` query:

```
WolframAlpha["United States 30 year treasury bond monthly", {{"History:Treasury:EconomicData", 1}, "TimeSeriesData"}];
    
Length@%
    
460
```

I haven't done this in a while, but `FinancialData` didn't used to do this.  This seems like something that has appeared in `FinancialData` since it began outputting `TimeSeries` objects.

I know I can extract the monthly data from the `TimeSeries`, just seems odd.

Have I missed something?
Thoughts|suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Maybe use a fuller specification like `FinancialData["SP500", {"Jan. 1, 1978", "Feb. 7, 2023", "Month"}]` ?

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what - That most curiously works.  Still odd that the old way doesn't.  I'd love to know why?